# How to downgrade Java -version in Mac

Tags: java, macos, version, downgrade

tried the below commands in Mac Terminal and did not update the java version:

**/usr/libexec/java_home -V**

**export JAVA_HOME=“System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home”**

**Updated again**
Fixed it ! **export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.8`** worked

**note:**

- please use ` and not ' in your terminal command.
- also only: /usr/libexec/java_home takes effect and not the System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/.

Verified version afterwards using:
Java -version

validated and all good now.
Downgraded! Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Even though you already solved it, using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) greatly reduces stress if you want to switch regularly between versions.